# Вывод постов в табах - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Идея такова, есть библиотека jQuery UI Tabs

Хочу создать посты в которых будут кастомфилды:

- чекбокс
- начальная дата и конечная дата

Подскажите, как правильно сделать выборку постов?

- Tab 1: Все события
- Tab 2: Текущие события (Посты у которых текущая дата между начальной и конечной датой)
- Tab 3: Прошедшие события
- Tab 4: Онлайн события (Посты у которых отмечен чекбокс, например `is_online`)

Есть какие-то идеи, не делать же в каждом ТАБе свою выборку?

```html
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Все события</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Текущие</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Прошедшие</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-4">Онлайн</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <h2>Content heading 1</h2>
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <h2>Content heading 2</h2>
    <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <h2>Content heading 3</h2>
    <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-4">
    <h2>Content heading 4</h2>
    <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Можно конечно по категориям их раскидать, но мне не хочется этого делать, хотя будет проще.

Comment: Сделайте выборку один раз, потом выводите полученный массив постов 4 раза в 4х циклах, по циклу на таб. И в каждом цикле проверяйте условия вывода.

Comment: угу, спасибо. Идею примерно понял.